# Create Database Dynamically Using C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to create a database using this code:

```
var createDatabaseQuery = "exec ('CREATE DATABASE ' + @db)";

var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(createDatabaseQuery, sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@db", SqlDbType.Text);
sqlCommand.Parameters["@db"].Value = "DbName";

sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The above works perfectly but I try to do concatenation as follows, it throws an exception:

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(createDatabaseQuery, sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@db", SqlDbType.Text);
sqlCommand.Parameters["@db"].Value = "DbName" + CustomId; //Doing the concatenation here
```

Exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '-'

I know, there could be better ways to do it. But is there any way that I can make the above work?

Comment: Why is there a `-` in your query, is it from the CustomId? What happens if you change the query to `exec ('CREATE DATABASE @db')` or simply `CREATE DATABASE @db`?

Comment: The same thing occurs @Luke Vo.

Comment: What does `CustomId` contain? It is odd the error identifies the “-“ character, yet I do not see that character anywhere in the query. Are you sure the error is coming from the posted query?

Comment: I am using guid for the CustomId @JohnG. Got it and worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you are quoting the name correctly using `QUOTENAME`, because it contains characters that need escaping.

```cs
var createDatabaseQuery = "exec ('CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@db))";
```

---

Also, the parameter type should be `nvarchar(128)`

```cs
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@db", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = "DbName" + CustomId;
```

Answer (score 3):

Time to learn the real intricate sides of SQL.

The way you wan t to write it - is incorrect in multiple ways. DEBUG THE SQL. Do not care about the C# code, look at the SQL...

In your case - naming conversions.

Tables, databases etc. can not contains a "-" - OR they must be marked.

CREATE DATABASE my-database -> Error
CREATE DATABASE [my-database] -> correct, the [] brackets names and thus... no processing of the "-" is tried.

This is quite clear in the SQL documentation, but a part many people overlook (mostly because in most cases it does not matter). They likely wonder why generators bracket every item name (Database, schema, table, COLUMN). Well, that is the reason. What do you think "-1" means? Minus one, processing, or part of a name - the server has no way to determine this. Help him.